# <controlName> is ambiguous in the namespace ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio Website project, which gives me an error on compiling all of a sudden - it used to work just fine.

It tells me that my "Validator_ascx" control is ambiguous in the namespace ASP.

I've read a lot of topics about this particular problem, but none solved my issue so far. Things I've tried include:

- Check for doubles. There are NONE. Nothing else is called Validator in my entire project.
- Rebuild/Clean Website
- Rename control and update reference in Web.config
- Changed the TEMP build folder to a new folder via web.config, to make sure that nothing remains from previous builds.
- Tried putting my code-behind of Validator (Validator.ascx.cs) into a new namespace.
- Tried turning 'batch' compilation to 'false' in web.config

All of them lead to the exact same error. I'm getting desperate. Does anyone else have any ideas of things I can try? I've lost almost an entire day due to this error.

Thanks for any ideas you might have.

Comment: If you just remove the validator, the code compiles without an problem?

Comment: Any chance compiled DLL of the project is in the Bin folder?

Comment: If I take away the validator, it doesn't compile at all, because the validator is used all over the website.

Comment: Have you tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/904018/989348

Comment: Yes, I've tried putting batch compilation to 'false' in the web.config. That's essentially what he's doing. Same problem.

Comment: Did you notice `Abdul Saboor` suggestion in the same SO question taken from http://www.netomatix.com/development/usercontrols2.aspx might help specifying a classname? It's almost like it is trying to compile the control multiple times.

Comment: Yes, If I try to put the ClassName there, then the error message will simply change to 'ClassName is ambiguous in the namespace ASP', where 'ClassName' is what I've entered ...